# Salesforce API - Error: sObject type 'Organization' is not supported

Tags: api, salesforce

My company runs a SaaS application and we have hundreds of organizations integrated with Salesforce. For one customer in particular we are receiving the following error when attempting to authenticate to the API.

```
Error: sObject type 'Organization' is not supported.
```

On a Salesforce forum someone suggests that `View All Data` permissions are required to access the Organization object. I'm not entirely sure this is accurate.

How are permissions for this object configured?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it is a permission issue, I'm guessing you have a controller build to authenticate for you, if you change it to `without sharing`, it should fix your issue

```
public without sharing class Foo {}
```